# C++ casting from lvalue reference to rvalue reference a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, reference, perfect-forwarding

I'm studying the perfect forwarding mechanism in C++ and I have some questions about the `std::move()` function. This is a possible implementation:

```
template<class T> 
typename remove_reference<T>::type&&
std::move(T&& a) noexcept {
  typedef typename remove_reference<T>::type&& RvalRef;
  return static_cast<RvalRef>(a);
}
```

When used on `std::unique_ptr<>`, this function transfers the ownership of a resource from one pointer to another.
I found out that the focal point of this function is the casting from an lvalue reference to an rvalue reference to the deduced `T` type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    unique_ptr<int> p1(new int(20));
    unique_ptr<int> p2;
    unique_ptr<int> &r = p1;

    cout << "p1 = " << p1.get() << endl;
    cout << "p2 = " << p2.get() << endl;

    // These 2 instructions produce the same effect (then consider just one of them).
    p2 = static_cast<unique_ptr<int>&&>(r);
    //p2 = move(p1);

    cout << "p1 = " << p1.get() << endl;
    cout << "p2 = " << p2.get() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
p1 = 0x467b10
p2 = 0
p1 = 0
p2 = 0x467b10
```

I wanted to know what happens when I cast from an L reference to an R reference a `std::unique_ptr<int>` type.

Comment: there is no run time action. it is just a change of perceived kind of expression. which influences what actions using that expression in some context, may result in (in particular overload resolution).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::move` does not move, `std::forward` does not forward.

`move` just casts one kind of reference to another.  It takes a reference, and returns an rvalue reference to the same data.  This does nothing at run time.  What does the move is the code that consumes this rvalue reference.

That code is now told 'treat this much like you would a temporary unnamed object'  (not quite, but close).  The most common consumer is a "move constructor" or "move assignment", which is what does the actual move with `unique_ptr`.

As for `forward`, it is a conditional move defined to work with a technique called 'perfect forwarding' and/or 'universal references'.  It sometimes moves, sometimes does nothing.  I only mention it because the pithy saying I quoted above mentions it: it is another topic.

Comment: Pedantic: the one-argument version of `std::move` does not move :)

Comment: Does std::move nothing at runtime, because the standard mandates it, or becaue the compiler will *probably* optimize the function call away? I'm aware that - as you stated - std::move itself doesn't do any move operation, but as far as I can tell, std::move(a) is a standard STL function call which is in no way *guaranteed* to have no runtime cost.

Comment: Then it's better to static cast to rvalue reference instead of `std::move()`?

Comment: @MikeMB the standard rarely prevents compilers from inserting `for (int i = 0; i < 1 billion; ++i)` at arbitrary points.  It could even do so with `std::move` only.  Or the compiler could convert said references to pointers, push a pointer on the stack, pop the identical pointer off, and call it `std::move`.  I would respect the first compiler more, it is at least honest with its inefficiency.  However, there is no reason why converting from one reference type to another as a cast should do anything at run time.

Comment: @biowep no.  `std::move` says "I am marking this for moving purposes", and is better known than `static_cast<Foo&&>(foo)` (where `Foo` is a value type not a reference type).  (To understand the implementation of `std::move` above, you want to learn about the technique of universal references)

Comment: @T.C. The saying is pithy enough to be useful even if false.  :)

Comment: @Yakk: What I mean is that compilers usually start (-o0 and -g) with translating the code as it is, meaning that each c++ statement is translated into one or more according assembler statements and it doesn't even treat STL functions any differently than ordinary user provided functions. That's why I would expect move(a) to be translated into a function call. For release purposes you'd of course turn on optimizations and any decent compiler would inline it and optimize it away. What I was wondering is, whether this is a wrong view and move is instead really treated as a keyword or a cast.